# "Гастро-Крым" — верно написано?

Tags: словообразование, ономастика, дефис, приставка, сложные-слова

*«Гастро-Крым».* Верно ведь написание с дефисом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, правильно с дефисом.

> 7. На общем основании иноязычные приставки ***анти-, архи-, гипер-, интер-, инфра-, контр-, пост-, суб-, супер-, транс-, ультра-, экстра-*** и др. пишутся слитно: *антинародный* (но: *Анти-Дюринг* — перед именем собственным)...
>
> Иноязычные начальные составные части ***квази-, псевдо-, пан-*** также пишутся слитно: *квазинаучный, псевдокультура, пангерманский.* (Но: *квази-Пушкин, пан-Европа* — перед именем собственным).

Источник: [**Сложные слова без соединительной гласной**](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=47) (Розенталь).